# Change pixels color

Tags: colors, pixel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selective Color of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845973/selective-color-of-image)

I am trying to do something with image processing. I am trying to open an image and then user will select a part of the image. I am finding the average of this selected part as selected color. Now user will select another color from a palette of colors and I am trying to change the color of the image with the new selected one.

To be more concrete. If in an image with apples and oranges user selectes a part from an orange then I have to change the color of oranges to the new color. So, every orange from now on will have another color.

I tried this with c#, by converting RGB to HSV and then I was trying to keep the saturation and brightenes of original image and changing just hue value but it is not working properly.

Any idea about this problem ?